# Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/RNFetchBlob/RNFetchBlobConst;

Tags: java, android, react-native, build, apk

I'm getting this error after i try to build APK, Any ideas?

Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/RNFetchBlob/RNFetchBlobConst;

Error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/RNFetchBlob/RNFetchBlobConst;

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/RNFetchBlob/RNFetchBlobConst;

Comment: Do you have multidex enabled in your grade file

Comment: @KunalParte Yes, if i disable it or  enable it, it won't export it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by switching from react-native-fetch-blob to rn-fetch-blob.

Answer (score 0):

add in gradle.property this line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
```

after that clean and rebuild project

Answer (score 0):

```
Multidex exception intends that your app and libraries it references exceeds 65536 methods which means it has crossed the limit of Android build architecture.

There are possible reasons for your Multidex exception.
May be you have missed on something while enabling Multidex in you app.

I would suggest you to go through the documentation and also go through the limitations of Multidex.

If your minSdkversion is set to 21 the you just need to add following in your module level grade file:

android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

}

 However, if your minSdkVersion set to 20 or low then you need to follow the following:

in your module level grade file add this:
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}

If you are not overriding Application class the add this in your manifest file application tag:

    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>

if you override Application class then just replace Application with MultiDexApplication like this :

public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }


if you don not override Application class and you cannot change your base class then add this:
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}

following is the link for MultiDex documentation
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex
```